# How can I mock IP address for unit tests in Express js

Tags: node.js, express

I've implemented this mock, but I don't like it because it requires me to have mock code in my real app, whereas I would like it better if I could mock it in some other way without having mock variables in my real app.

```
const ipValidator = (req, res, next) => {
  let ip = req.connection.remoteAddress

  const MOCK = req.app.get('MOCK')
  if (MOCK && MOCK.IP) {
    ip = MOCK.IP
  }

  if (isUsIp(ip)) {
    next()
    return
  }

  res.end()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting the mock right in the code, manipulate `req.connection.remoteAddress` in the unit test directly. That way you can remove the `req.app.get('MOCK')` call from within your route.

Comment: I want to test my end points fully, not just individual or grouped controllers/middlewares. I've tried mocking app.handle and replacing req.connection.remoteAddress but I was not successful. The real ip was still passed for some unknown reason. I don't know how to else to mock (req, res) for a real end point request.